# mysql stored procedure fails with FK error but the same lines run individually succeed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I have a bookings table and an orders table. Each booking is part of an order, and therefore stores an intOrderID as a foreign key. I have the following MySQL procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_archive` (
  IN p_dtmBefore DATE
  )
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO tblArchivedOrders SELECT * FROM tblOrders O WHERE (SELECT MAX(dtmDateTime) FROM tblBookings WHERE intOrderID = O.intOrderID) < p_dtmBefore;
INSERT INTO tblArchivedBookings SELECT * FROM tblBookings WHERE intOrderID IN (SELECT intOrderID FROM tblArchivedOrders);

DELETE FROM tblBookings WHERE intOrderID IN (SELECT intOrderID FROM tblArchivedOrders);  
DELETE FROM tblOrders WHERE intOrderID IN (SELECT intOrderID FROM tblArchivedOrders);

COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

which fails with the following message

```
Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mjlprodu_CGUA_test`.`tblBookings`, CONSTRAINT `tblBookings_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`intOrderID`) REFERENCES `tblOrders` (`intOrderID`))
```

I read the message as saying that there is still a booking in tblBookings that references an order in tblOrders that I'm trying to delete, and so I can't delete that order. However, if I run this query

```
SELECT * FROM tblOrders WHERE intOrderID IN (SELECT intOrderID FROM tblArchivedOrders) AND  intOrderID IN (SELECT intOrderID FROM tblBookings)
```

it returns no rows.

So I have commented out the "DELETE FROM tblOrders .." line, and the procedure runs OK. I then run the "DELETE FROM tblOrders .." line by itself, and that runs OK too!

How on earth can this happen?

Comment: Your procedure uses a transaction. When it got the error, the transaction was rolled back, so none of the insertions were done. That's why your query returned no rows.

Comment: Why don't you use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign keys, so the child rows will be deleted automatically when you delete the parents?

Comment: Er .. because I didn't know about it! Sounds great, thanks